# How to suppress a key from sending using Blazor and KeyBoardEventArgs

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side, keyboard-events

I have a inputfield with a onkeydown Event.
I'm scanning some numbers in with a scanner. The scanner config is to read the barcode and then send a Tab.
So if a Tab is sent the Number is added to a list. By JS it sets the value of the inputfield back to null and then focus on the inputfield again.

The problem is that Tab is still sent after my function is done and so the focus is not anymore on my inputfield. How can I suppress the Tab Key in this case?

```
enter code here
private async void addToTable(KeyboardEventArgs args)
{
  if (args.Key != "Tab")
  {
    LeNumber += args.Key.ToString();
  }
  else
  {
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(LeNumber))
    {
        if (todos.Contains(LeNumber))
        {
            LeNumber = null;
            await TurnRed("table");
            await Focus("LeNumber");

        }
        else
        {
            if (LeNumber == "submit")
            {
                generateXml();
                b += 1;
            }
            else
            {

                todos.Add(LeNumber);
                LeNumber = null;                    
                await SetValueBack("LeNumber");
                await Focus("LeNumber");
                await TurnNormal("table");
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Why are you doing this with oninput? Use the standard onchange : When the scanner sends the Tab key, the input will lose focus and the onchange event will fire  - you process the value, and then set focus back on the input.

Comment: So u mean that I should solve this with pure JS? The @onchange Event in Blazor can't capture a Key

Comment: No, I'm questioning why you need to capture a key at all. if you let the tab key through it will trigger onchange which you can handle in Blazor

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
<input value="@LeNumber" type="text" @onkeydown="@addToTable" @onkeydown:preventDefault="@isPreventDefault" />

@code {

    private string LeNumber{ get; set; }
    private bool isPreventDefault { get; set; }

    private void onKeydown(KeyboardEventArgs args)
    {
        if(args.Key == "Tab")
        {
            this.isPreventDefault = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Then remove the Tab test from your handler.

There is a similar method to stop propogation. https://www.meziantou.net/how-to-use-event-preventdefault-in-blazor.htm

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to use a lambda expression to separate your logic in case of a 'Tab', in your `<input/>`?

```
 <input type="text" class="form-control" @onkeydown="@(e => { if (e.Key != "Tab") MyMethod(e); else MyMethod2(e); })" />
```

In MyMethod2 you can have separate logic in case of Tab key (such as to place focus back on the input).

```
      @code
        {
        private void MyMethod(KeyboardEventArgs e)
                {
                    MyNumber += e.Key;
                }
        
                private async void MyMethod2(KeyboardEventArgs e)
                {
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(MyNumber)
                       AllMyNumbers.Add(MyNumber);
                    MyNumber = "";
                    await jsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("FocusOnInputAndClearInputValue");
                   //Even if Tab key is sent several times, focus will be sent back to input each time...
                }
        }
```

Comment: I have here the same Issue. The Tab is sent after the functions are done so I have here the same problem

Comment: OK - Perhaps I understand the process wrong: (1) - Enter lots of keys, and add each to string LeNumber. (2) - Scanner sends a Tab key: Add LeNumber to my list of strings (todos).  Focus back to my input and clear values. (3): Your problem is that then Tab is sent again?

Comment: Yes the Tab is sent after my Function is done. So it just capture the Tab Key is pressed but it  is effectively sent after my Function is done.

Comment: I see.  However, when the Tab key is sent after your function is done, it should again call the "MyMethod2" as in my above example - which will place focus back on the input yet again.  I just tested, and even holding in the tab key for a while - it eventually focuses back on input once Tab stops sending. I'll expand my answer - Let me know if I misunderstand :)

Comment: It doesn't work for me. I don't know where the problem is. Everytime it clears the inputfield but the focus goes up where the URL is, like the focus function would not exist. Maybe I did something else wrong. But thanks a lot for ur help!